# How to set the style of windows in caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

In calibrun micro, the main window is created by caliburn and I have no access to it. How can style it. For example I want to make it un-resize-able and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caliburn micro has *WindowManager* class. You can create your own class derived from this one and override *CreateWindow* method.

Example:

```
public class CustomWindowManager : WindowManager
{
       protected override Window CreateWindow(object rootModel, bool isDialog, object context)
        {
             var window = base.CreateWindow(rootModel, isDialog, context);

             window.Style = YourCustomStyle; 

             return window;
        }
}
```

Comment: I created a similar custom window manager, but how ask caliburn micro to use it? My CreateWindow never calls by Caliburn?

Comment: @mans You have to register the WindowManager with the IOC container. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061595/caliburn-micro-wpf-window-management